# strong params in letsrate gem is not creating rates on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new in rails, I install letsrate gem, and now i think have trouble with Strong Parameters,   letsrate gem is not creating rates on submit... How add strong parameters to rater controller?

```
class RaterController < ApplicationController 

  def create                                  
    if current_user.present?
      obj = eval "#{params[:klass]}.find(#{params[:id]})"     
      if params[:dimension].present?
        obj.rate params[:score].to_i, current_user.id, "#{params[:dimension]}"       
      else
        obj.rate params[:score].to_i, current_user.id 
      end

      render :json => true 
    else
      render :json => false        
    end
  end                                        


end
```

Help please...

Answer (score 0):

need delete attr_accessible in model :)